# OnPrepareOptionsMenu gets called after menu creation

Tags: android, menu

Iam trying to understand a phenomenon .I have an Integer **field called "new"** which **I add a condition for in onPrepareOptionsMenu** and on its basis I change a menu item title like so:-

```
   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        if(new==1) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.folder).setTitle("new folder");
        }else
            menu.findItem(R.id.doc).setTitle("new document");

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**"new"** gets called in one of my Activites methods and **when its value changes** **onPrepareOptionsMenu** gets called and the changes occur .

What I know is that it should get called before **onCreateOptionsMenu** which was called only once at the start of the activity(*I didn't recall the activity*) . **So how come onPrepareOptionsMenu got recalled ?.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called only once when activity is started, where as  `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` is called every time you open a menu to update it when displayed.

Comment: I see ,so by clicking on the top right menu item list `onPrepareOptionsMenu` gets recalled ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want optionsMenu to be refreshed, just call

```
invalidateOptionsMenu()
```

`onPrepareOptionsMenu()` will be recalled then